# return NOT NULL columns from class with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

In python [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) I would like to get the `nullable=False` columns of my 
class, including JSONB types.

Here's my example class:

```
class MyClass():
    __tablename__ = 'myclass'
    id = Column("id", primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    body = Column(JSONB, nullable=False)
    irrelevant = Column(String, nullable=True)
```

Using the module [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) I can get the members of `MyClass` and apply a filter:

```
# list of possible attributes
attr = [a for a in inspect.getmembers(MyClass,lambda :not(inspect.isroutine(a))) if not '__' in  a[0]]
```

But it is not possible to check if `nullable=False` is in a column.
Eventually I want to get the columns: `name` and `body`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over `MyClass.__table__.columns` and get names of not nullable columns

```
column_names = [col.name for col in MyClass.__table__.columns if not col.nullable]
```

Then get attributes with `getattr`

```
attrs = [getattr(MyClass, column_name) for column_name in column_names]
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: type object 'MyClass' has no attribute '__table__'`

Comment: You need to create base class with `declarative_base()` : http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html#basic-use

Comment: perfect; but how to exclude `id` which has no `nullable=False`

Comment: got it: `column_names = [col.name for col in Request.__table__.columns if not col.nullable and not col.primary_key]`